# Using Cloud Code with the Parse Server and Heroku

Tags: ios, swift, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I am trying to understand the new Parse Server and have deployed on Heroku. This went smoothly but what I am struggling with is figuring out how to write server side code (Cloud Code). I've read over the parse server example many times so I must be missing something but I'm very unclear if I should be using Express for something, or how I even begin to include my Cloud Code files. Any help is very much appreciated.

UPDATE:

I found the cloud folder I was just looking in the wrong place. I moved it and index.js to my apps folder on the desktop. I have changed the default code in main.js to my custom code. I have set up index.js with my apps information. The problem now is when I run the app and try to call the cloud code functions I get error invalid function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have the parse server example running on heroku you are 90 percent there. Just open the `cloud/main.js` file and start adding your cloud code. There should be a hello cloud function there as an example.

To use your already created cloud code modules/files you can require them as you have done before on parse.com. The only difference is that the path should now be relative instead of absolute. For example `require('cloud/cloudFunctions');` should be `require('./cloudFunctions');` if you had a module called `cloudFunctions.js` in the cloud directory.

Cloud Code works similar to how it did on `parse.com` and you shouldn't have to think too much about expressjs for simple applications. That said, parse server is using expressjs so yes you are using it.

Parse server is simply a another node module similar to the other thousands available. If you do not have previous experience with nodejs, running parse server can seem complicated. Therefore I would recommend reading about the basics of nodejs before a full migration.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I still have a few questions. I used the "Deploy to Heroku" button and don't have a main.js file. Could you point me in the direction of a the correct way to deploy to heroku that would include the main.js file? I will definitely read about nodejs.

Comment: Aha! Did you run `heroku git:clone -a yourAppName` to get your files locally after using the deploy button? If so you should have gotten a cloud directory with a main.js file? To continue making updates you can read about deployment on heroku here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I did but where is the main.js file suposed to appear? Because I haven't been able to seem to find it.

Comment: Strange! Did you get the cloud folder?

Comment: It should be in your root directory? You can change the name however, as long as you update the path in your parse server initialize code.

Comment: How about the resource limits? Legacy Parse.com has a limit of 3sec for before/after save hooks. Is that the case with Parse Server?

Comment: Nope. No such limits.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the Bitnami stack on a Google Compute Engine instance and I had a similar problem to yours. To solve it, just navigate to the folder where your server.js file is and create a folder called "cloud". Then create the main.js file inside the cloud folder with the following content:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(req, res) {
  res.success('Hi');
});
```

Now open the server.js file and find the line containing the path to the cloud code file. Change it to point to you main.js file like this:

[image: server.js config file]

This could be any arbitrary folder of your choosing.
Now just restart your parse server and call the cloud function:

```
String result = ParseCloud.callFunction("hello", new HashMap<>());
```

This is with the Java SDK but should not be much different. The variable result will equal "Hi" if you've used the function from above.

Comment: I am using the Bitnami Stack also, but as soon as I change the cloud parameter from ./node_modules/parse-server/lib/cloud-code/Parse.Cloud.js to ./cloud/main.js my website stops running - I try to append my cloud code to the Parse.Cloud.js file also but even then it stops working. I need to migrate my own cloud code to the server, how do I do that? Thank you.

Comment: @Meeyam Please check the parse logs and post any errors messages. I found most errors can be solved easily this way. When you stop the server it'll tell you where the log is located.