# Using Parse Cloud Code with Parse Server Heroku

Tags: heroku, parse-platform

I am hosting my Parse Server Heroku. The setup was very smooth and everything is working fine with me now. I have Parse Cloud Code that I need to setup I found a way to do it from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35787721/using-cloud-code-with-the-parse-server-and-heroku) from StackOverFlow. I have uploaded the cloud code to my parse server github repository you check the screenshot. But when I deploy this repository to Heroku I get Application Error. When I deploy the normal version of Parse Server its works fine.

[image: Cloud Code Added to the Cloud directory of Parse Server]

Answer (score 0):

You should only have main.js in your cloud code directory. Make sure your cloud variable in index.js links correctly to it. Should be something like

```
cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js'
```

To make this easier you should install Heroku command line tools and clone your project from there by using

```
heroku git:clone -a project-name
```

Afterward try adding your cloud code in that project and pushing back to Heroku with

```
git push heroku master
```